# Perl array of arrays in loop

Tags: perl

How can I add array to list of arrays ( 2D array ) in perl ?
This option not working / example:

```
my @db;
my $i = 0;
my @random;
while($i < 10) {
    @random = genNum(49, 6);
    @db[$i++] = @random;
}

print $db[3][1] . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have changed a little code and it seems that is good:

```
my @db;
my $i = 0;
my @random;
while($i < 10) {
    @random = genNum(49, 6);
    push( @{$db[$i++]}, @random);
}
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) {
        print join(", ", @{$db[$i++]}) . "\n";

}
```